# Android Wear DataLayer API usage for synchronizing when phone app is closed

Tags: android, wear-os, google-datalayer

So, I want to learn this synchronization strategy instead of just using the simpler MessageAPI, but am really struggling with how to successfully implement this.

My project is like this:  I make queries to download a small amount of text from an API, via my phone.  I will make these queries every so often, haven't really decided on how often just yet.  The data will update the watch, which should hold onto the last data received.  After that first download occurs, I send data using a DataMap, to the Android Watch.  I only send that once, because I believe that sets up a channel to continually send updates when ready.  If that is wrong, please correct me.

My main question is this:  what if the Android phone's app closes?  Then the data object goes to null, and gets sent to the Watch as null?  Or, should I send an object from a long-running service or shared preferences on the Android phone, so that the object is never null?

Comment: I'm afraid you're not understanding the Data API correctly. The "channel" is maintained by the Wear system and isn't to do with whether your app is running or not. When you update a DataMap, it gets sent to the watch *and* persists in the Data layer independent of your app. IOW, it doesn't "go to null" when your app closes. The Data layer doesn't care if your app is running at any given time.

Comment: but if the object you put into the dataMap is destroyed along with the application, then wouldnt that cause a data-changed event to occur and hence update the Watch with null data?

Comment: Not unless your app deletes it from the Data API before it closes. This is what I meant when I said it "persists in the Data layer independent of your app." Once you've put some data into the API, it really doesn't matter whether your app remains running or not.

Comment: But then wouldn't this suggest that the object isn't actually synchronized, and that some manually change-event must be sent by the user?  If the object originally put into the Datamap is destroyed, then how does it not get deleted from the Data Layer?  If synchronization is supposed to occur?  Is there a manual signal the coder must do to signal that they want to send a changed/modified value for the original object?

Comment: The original object _isn't_ synchronized, of course - you're thinking about "objects" too literally. It's all just data in the device's memory, right? A copy of that data is what is sent to the other device. And it's the act of you putting data into the API that triggers the synchronization; that is the only "signal" involved.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the Data Layer as more of an event system, i.e., you update your data and you're notified on the other side when the data is updated (created, changed, or deleted). You don't have to worry about if the Activity is killed after that. Even if the data was 'deleted', you would be notified it was deleted.

On the Wear device, you would listen for the changes via a Service or Activity and update UI, DB, etc. accordingly.

It probably make sense to read through [this](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) Android training guide. (It isn't too long.) The [Handling Data Layer Events](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html) section is probably the most useful.